# python-eve generate _etag, _updated and _created

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I added data directly to mongodb and now i'm missing the _etag, _created and _updated fields. How do I generate these for documents that don't have them?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A `GET` on those document will transparently get those meta for you. The two date fields will probably default to epoch; etag will be computed for you. This way you will then be able to make conditional requests (`PUT`, `PATH`, `DELETE`) on the documents, like they were inserted via the API. Remember you can also opt to [disable conditional](http://python-eve.org/features.html#disabling-concurrency-control) requests altogheter